# Is a planet where Chemosynthesis replaces photosynthesis possible?

Tags: science-fiction, flora, biochemistry

Specifically, using atmospheric/dissolved sulfur compounds to power energy-producing chemical reactions in **Plant-like** organisms

Im looking to make a planet where due to a thick cloudy atmosphere, photosynthesis only really exists in the upper atmosphere and chemosynthesis is the primary form of energy production, so "plants" have evolved to use Chemsynthesis instead of Photosynthesis.

EDIT:  Was thinking that this world was relatively new (say, 2.5-2.6 billion years old), or the sulfur gets replenished by decomposers releasing the sulfur compounds back into the environment from dead autotrophs, or a series of geothermal activity releases new sulfur along with the compounds being recycled

EDIT 2; ELECTRIC BOOGALOO: When I mean "energy production" I mean it in how  it's the baseline for energy in an ecosystem

Edit 3: im sorry for my lack of knowledge in biochemistry, my only real experience with it was a high school biology class I had in freshman year of high school, I was fully and well aware of Chemosynthetic organisms existing on Earth, I'm just curious on if complex, multicellular life based on chemosynthesis is possible and not just Microbes

Comment: Given that there are examples of chemosynthesis on Earth, what makes you think that there would be any impediment to it being the primary form of energy production on a world with some impediment to photosynthesis?

Comment: Your organisms will eventually run out of sulfur. On Earth they do not run out of CO2 because animals make more, and the energy to power this cycle ultimately comes from the sun. But you say  little light reaches the surface on your planet. So where does the energy come from? WHERE DOES IT COME FROM REDFROGCRAB?

Comment: Photo- and chemosynthesis are **not** forms of energy production. They are forms of energy storage. Both photo- and chemosynthesis need a source of [free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_free_energy) to work; in the case of photosynthesis, that's the light of the sun. Some chemosynthetic organisms here on Earth use the energy supplied by [hydrothermal vents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent). (Note that "free energy" is a technical term; it does not mean energy which can be had for free.)

Comment: Gonna get really specific here: are Chemosynthetic plants possible?

Comment: @redfrogcrab no, because then they wouldn’t be plants

Comment: @sphennings was thinking that due to either a thick, cloudy atmosphere that blocked out most light or life just having to exist entirely underground, photosynthesis never really took off to Earth scales, while Chemosynthesis eventually did.

Comment: @Daron It comes from organisms putting sulfur back into circulation and new sulfur being pumped out by hydrothermal vents in the seas of said world and geothermal activity on the surface, and the energy comes from chemical reactions with sulfides (or other compounds), hence asking if Chemosyntheic "plants" are possible

Comment: @AlexP already addressed this, I used "production" because that's just how I see it, turning chemical reactions into something else that's usable

Comment: @Topcode I meant "plant" as a comparison because that's the closest thing I can think of to call a large, stationary multicellular autotroph that acts as a base line to an ecosystem's food web

Comment: @redfrogcrab What you have described sounds like tube worms. Immobile multicellular organisms that use chemosynthesis from sulphur vents.

Comment: @redfrogcrab well, if a main source is vents than you will have life on vents similar to the life on earth vents, however, you will not have much life elsewhere because chemicals wont diffuse that far. A highly volcanic world could have some areas with large life, but not a whole lot.

Comment: @Daron Kinda, Tube worms have a symbiotic relationship with Chemosynthetic microbes,  which would be like a coral (heterotroph (the worms in the tube worm and the cnidarian in coral)+autotrope (tubeworms: chemosynthetic organisms, coral: algea/photosynthetic eucaryotes))
I'm talking the whole organism is made of cells that can do chemosynthesis

Comment: @Topcode but could say, weather or atmospheric currents move around the chemicals farther on the surface? would just the atmosphere having a natural amount of sulfides be better? I know Venus has Sulfuric acid rain so I know it's possible.

Comment: Hello RedFrogCrab, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You're asking the wrong question and it's incredibly important that you understand why. As stated in the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build an imaginary world of your own creation. Is your idea possible? The answer is ***always*** yes because it's your world and your rules. Even asking "is this realistic" doesn't make a lot of sense on this site. On the other hand, asking for help developing the rules that allow the idea you want "possible" is exactly what we do. From that perspective, what is your problem? What can we help you do?

Comment: @redfrogcrab Venus, however, doesn’t have any organisms evolving to capture as much of that sulfur as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Welcome to PLANET EARTH!**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_cycle

> The sulfur cycle is a biogeochemical cycle in which the sulfur moves
> between rocks, waterways and living systems. It is important in
> geology as it affects many minerals and in life because sulfur is an
> essential element (CHNOPS), being a constituent of many proteins and
> cofactors, and sulfur compounds can be used as oxidants or reductants
> in microbial respiration.[1] The global sulfur cycle involves the
> transformations of sulfur species through different oxidation states,
> which play an important role in both geological and biological
> processes

No fiction here, RFG.  The sulfur cycle is real and sulfur metabolizing organisms are alive and well.  Probably you have some of these organisms in your colon right now.  I certainly do.

You can have sulfur metabolism on your world and lift it intact from terrestrial biochemistry.  The only problem for your fiction is you can't totally MSU with the sulfur cycle because informed folks will call you out in the most embarrassing ways.  Read up!

getting you started:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemosynthesis#Hydrogen_sulfide_chemosynthesis_process

Comment: Keep in mind that the biogenic chemosynthesis energy turnover is orders of magnitudes lower than the energy turnover of photosynthesis. Chemosynthesis is mostly limited to specialized bacteria/archea and close symbionts/predators (at least on earth).

Comment: @Matthias - having Old Sol with his deep pockets subsidizing our endeavors is pretty sweet.

Answer (score 0):

**Tube Worms**

[image]

Tube worms live in the deep ocean where there is no light. The bottom of their food chain is the chemicals and heat from hydrothermal vents or smokers. They are large immobile multicellular organisms that do chemo synthesis.

[image]

The chemo synthesis happens in part due to a bacteria that lives inside the tube worm. The bacteria cannot survive outside the tube worm so it makes sense to consider the tube and bacteria to be a single organism.

This is common in the animal kingdom. I can digest milk with the help of the creepy crawlies in my stomach. But we still just say "I can digest milk" since the creepy crawlies form a useful part of my metabolism.

It is certainly identical from a worldbuilding perspective exactly where the chemosynthesis happens. If you are not happy with symbiotic bacterial colonies and redefining the problem out of existence, then  just wait a million years for the bacterium to integrate itself more deeply into the tube ala mitochondria.